# Pandas pivot table ignoring zeros while taking mean

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying the following

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfout3 = pd.DataFrame({'Idx': MnthIdx,
                       'Col1': Val1,
                       'Col2': Val2,
                       'Col3': Val3)})

MeanTable1 = pd.pivot_table(dfout3, index=['Idx'], values=['Col1','Col2','Col3'], aggfunc=[np.mean])
```

But I would like to ignore zeros's while taking the mean for each of values. Is there way through pandas instead of me doing index for zeros and getting rid of them and taking mean of columns?

Comment: Since you flagged numpy... a = np.array([0,1,0,2,0,3]) then np.where(a>0,a,np.nan) yields   array([nan, 1.000, nan, 2.000, nan, 3.000])  so putting it together with nanmean...  np.nanmean(np.where(a>0,a,np.nan)) yields 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @ysearka's answer points into the right direction, it's not working (anymore?):

This is how the loop works for me:

```
for col in dfout3.columns:
   dfout3.loc[dfout3[col] == 0] = dfout3[col]mean()
```

Comment: .ix is deprecated I think

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a way to ignore zeros, but you can set them as the mean value before the `pivot` (which will give the same result):

```
for col in dfout3.columns:
    dfout3.ix[dfout3.col == 0,col] = dfout3.col.mean()
```